# Problem with 2 binary counters

Tags: digital-logic

I have 2 binary counter 74ls161. The first has an input clock of 80 hz. This circuit should increment by one the second counter when 9 (1001) is detected on first counter and at the same time reset the first one. The second counter should also reset when 8 (1000) is detected, but when I probe the outputs I don't see any waveform on the second counter's outputs which remain at 0 level. The most significant bit of the first counter also remains at 0 level.

Here is the schematics

Also the output of the least significant bit of the first counter

Finally there is the output of the second and third bit of the first counter. Somehow they are identical

[image: Here is the schematics]

[image: First Waveform]

[image: second and third]

Comment: It is for this reason that EEs use simulation tools.

Comment: Did you remember to connect power and ground for all of the DIPs?

Comment: yes I did. I even added some decoupling capacitors ..

Comment: These are synchronous counters. Clock them all from the same CLK, and use the Count Enable signals to cascade them as shown in the TTL Databook..